# How to trigger onKeyPress event of React with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm working on a project, and i have to trigger React `onKeyPress` event with Javascript, I was able to trigger the event in Mozilla with the following code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); 
evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 13)
elment.dispatch(evt);
```

but failed to do in Chrome as Chrome doesn't support `initKeyEvent`, is there any workaround?

P.S: I want to press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in the textarea.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550341/react-trigger-onchange-if-input-value-is-changing-by-state/42554283#42554283

Comment: I'd use the event constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: trigger onChange if input value is changing by state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550341/react-trigger-onchange-if-input-value-is-changing-by-state)

Comment: I want to press Enter in the textarea not to update its value, so for that, I have to trigger onkeypress event.