# React doesn't re-render the Virtual DOM after the state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that loads courses from RESTful API. After the courses have been loaded state is changed and the component should render `CourseCard` components with the loaded data.

The problem is that when `loadCourses()` method changes the state of the component no `CourseCard` is displayed

This is code of the component:

```js
class Courses extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      courses: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCourses(null);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CourseCategoriesBar loadCourses={this.loadCourses.bind(this)} />

        <div style={{
          paddingBottom: "120px",
          marginBottom: "30px",
        }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

              {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => {
                return (
                  <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12" key={i}>
                    <CourseCard type="e" key={i}/>
                  </div>
                );
              })}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  loadCourses(id) {
    if (!id) id = ""
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/courses/category/" + id;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => this.setState(response));  
  }
}
```

Comment: Never do binding directly in render instead do it always in constructor or use arrow function

Comment: @Think-Twice arrow function has the same pitfall binding in the render has (creating a new function on each render)

Comment: @Nick Zuber agreed but it’s not always. The arrow function also renders only once in certain cases. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031147/react-which-is-recommended-arrow-or-normal-function

Comment: @Think-Twice maybe we’re misunderstanding each other — an arrow function in the render method will create a new function on each render. Check the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html An arrow function defined on the class level will do the trick (only render once and bind the scope) 

Comment: Yes on class level it renders only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are not updating state, update the state like this

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => this.setState({courses : response.data});
```

Comment: You don't know the structure of the JSON.

Comment: since he is using map i believe its type of array.

Comment: I believe axios attaches JSON responses to `data` properties. Fetch does not. Just a note for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your fetch response is an array, not an object.

Which means you will have a state object with properties 0,1,2 etc (like any array) instead of 'courses'.

try to map your response to the `courses` attribute:

```
.then(response => this.setState({courses: response}))
```