# TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I'm new in ReactJs.
In my application, I have inserted the following code to  validate textArea, but when I type on it, it throws following error.

```
NewBrand.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateName' of undefined
        at handleNameChange (NewBrand.js:67)
        at TextArea._this.handleTextareaChange (TextArea.js:94)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:201)
        at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:461)
        at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:483)
        at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:581)
        at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:592)
```

My code looks like follows:

```
    handleNameChange(event) {
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
        name: {
            text: value,
            ...this.validateName(value)
        }
    });

    }

    isFormInvalid() {
        if(this.state.name.validateStatus !== 'success') {
            return true;
        }
    }

  validateName = (nameText) => {
            if(nameText.length === 0) {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'error',
                    errorMsg: 'Please enter the Brand name!'
                }
            } else if (nameText.length > POLL_QUESTION_MAX_LENGTH) {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'error',
                    errorMsg: `Name is too long (Maximum ${POLL_QUESTION_MAX_LENGTH} characters allowed)`
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'success',
                    errorMsg: null
                }
            }
        }
```

Please hepl me to resolve this issue

Comment: On which line its throwing an error?

Comment: Try binding your function to "this"

Comment: this.setState({

Comment: Sorry , I've put edited code.Yes its incorrect.

Comment: Actual code is:  this.setState({
            name: {
                text: value,
                ...this.validateName(value)
            }
        });

Comment: Please share the complete component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're hooking up the change handler (probably in your render method) your jsx looks something like this

```
<textarea onChange={ this.handleNameChange } ...
```

Change it to

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
}

<textarea onChange={this.handleNameChange} ...
```

This ensures that `this` still refers to the Component object when the change callback runs.

Please note you are not recommended to bind the function directly in render or anywhere else in the component except constructor. Because binding in render causes a new function to be created in bundle file every time the component renders so we are not recommended to do that.

Like wise wherever you have event handler functions bind them in constructor and use the reference like mentioned above

Comment: Never bind the function directly in render. You are not recommended to do that. Always do binding only in constructor

Comment: Also, you can wrap your function by anonymous function like ` <textarea onChange={ () => this.handleNameChange() } ... `

Comment: Now I'm getting  error at following line. Am I doing wrong to bind data? my code is :handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const brandData = {
            name: this.state.name.text
        }; it threows 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'

Comment: Sounds like you also need to bind your submit handler

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @chk.buddi Looks like you are having many issues in your component so please share the complete component code instead of piece of it so that we can take a look and correct the code if there are any mistakes we find

Comment: @think-twice Thanks for the edit. Since we're nitpicking performance, won't the arrow function you've added in render create a new closure on each call?

Comment: @JonasH You are welcome. My bad yes that will create a new function to be created every time it renders. I removed that in your answer.  This thread has detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031147/react-which-is-recommended-arrow-or-normal-function