# How to choose between class methods and properties in react?

Tags: reactjs, methods, properties

Consider the following code in react + ES6:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const myFunction=(x,y)=>{
   return x*y
   };

 class MyTest extends Component {
 // state comes here 
   myProperty=(x,y)=>{
      return x*y
   };

   myMethod(x,y){
    return x*y
   }

    render () {
      return (<div>
          <h2>Result of myMethod: {this.myMethod(2,3)}</h2>
          <h2>Result of myProperty: {this.myProperty(2,3)}</h2>
          <h2>Result of myFunction: {myFunction(2,3)}</h2>
        </div>
      );
  }
 }
  export default MyTest;
```

Here's what the output looks like:

- Result of myMethod: 6
- Result of myProperty: 6
- Result of myFunction: 6

Is there really a difference? Is one preferable to another?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the example that you shown, there is no big difference and they probably can be used interchangeable.

There are just a very little things like the fact that having an function expression declared outside, probably, internally, it won't get reacreated every time a class is instantiated. I honestly have to check the EcmaScript spec to verify it.

Things changes when you need to pass one of these functions as a reference to other functions and whether these destinations needs to access the original context or a new one.

Lambdas can't have other context than the one they're declared in, so they can be passed as references without troubles.

Instance methods, instead, needs to be bound to a context before they gets passed as references.

Have you ever seen this pattern?

```
constructor() {
  // ...
  this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this)
}

myMethod(x,y){
  return x*y
}
```

This just overwrite `myMethod` in the class scope with a copy of the same method bound with this context. Basically, exactly the same as:

```
myMethod = (x, y) => x * y
```

Comment: Can I think of it this way:

* If you don't need *this* to access inside the object, use the external function (myFunction in the example)

* If you do need *this* , use the arrow function, myProperty in the example

* If you encounter existing methods - such as *render* in react, bear in mind you need to bind them if you want to access them from outside the object

Comment: I couldn't have explained it better :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would recommend you to go with functional component i.e., the function which you have declared outside class is the right one to go in your case. Because you are passing in input and expecting output and there is no state management inside that function. So it’s good to go with functional component.

Regarding using arrow function or normal function, check below thread for detailed answer

[React: Which is recommended arrow or normal function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031147/react-which-is-recommended-arrow-or-normal-function)

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction` can be viewed a **private method** of the `MyTest` class since `myFunction` is **not** being exported.

The difference between `myMethod` and `myProperty` is that `myProperty` uses the ES6 arrow function syntax.

In JavaScript, using the ES6 syntax for a method is not yet part of the EcmaScript standard. You'd need to use babel to convert it to ES5 syntax. The benefit of using the ES6 syntax is that you don't need to bind the `myProperty` to `this`, but you do need to bind `myMethod` (otherwise `this.myMethod` is `undefined`).

I don't think it's right to call it `myProperty`, however, since it is still a method. A property would be something like `myProperty = {something: 5}`. Basically, it's a property/attribute of the object, but not an action.

- Property of a car: `{color: "red"}` or `myColor = "red"`
- Method of a car: `drive()`