# Exporting functional and class components in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a [ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) in VS Code and I'm not sure which "type" of export use. If export should be at the class / functional component declaration or at the end of the file.

In the code below, I have 2 class components exports and 3 functional components exports.

Which of these is reccomended?

```
// ****************************************
// 1. rcc
// ****************************************
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class myComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

// ****************************************
// 2. rce
// ****************************************
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class myComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default myComponent

// ****************************************
// 3. rfc
// ****************************************
import React from 'react'

export default function myComponent() {
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

// ****************************************
// 4. rfce
// ****************************************
import React from 'react'

function myComponent() {
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default myComponent

// ****************************************
//  5. rafc
// ****************************************
import React from 'react'

const myComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default myComponent
```

My second question is about functional components - It is better (recommended) to write a functional component as an arrow function or classical function declaration?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: Which is recommended arrow or normal function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031147/react-which-is-recommended-arrow-or-normal-function)

Answer (score 1):

Dan Abramov said in his [tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1093901838179618816):

> JS tip: no matter which export style you prefer (default or named) or
>   which function style you use (arrow or declaration), make sure your
>   functions have names! Especially important for React components to
>   show up named in DevTools and warnings.

And, between using `rce` and `rcc` for exporting class components: It's up to you to decide, however, as in [CRA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/importing-a-component) documentation `rce` is used:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './Button'; // Import a component from another file

class DangerButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button color="red" />;
  }
}

export default DangerButton;
```

With this style, you can use [HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) easily, for this example we want to warp our class component into a Higher Order Component provided by a library:

```
import { injectIntl} from "react-intl";

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const intl = this.props.intl;
    const title = intl.formatMessage({
        id: "button.title",
        defaultMessage: "Hello!"
      });
    return <Button title={title}>...</Button>;
  }
}
export default injectIntl(Button);
```

And between using the Functional components vs Class components: Please refer to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), functional components are easier to write and to test, and now with React's [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) hook you can use state in your functional components. For class components read [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export multiple component in a file then you have to use only `export ComponentName` (without default).

then you can import as

```
import {ComponentA,ComponentB,...} from '../directory'
```

the other case is that you can export only one component in a file as

```
export default Class extends ........{} //
```

or

```
export default Class; // at the end of file
```

Both are same.

and you can import with any name

`import Class from '../directory'`